# Calling nested batch files in Windows 2008 R2 task scheduler

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to schedule a batch file in Windows 2008 R2 Server. My batch file internally calls two other batch files.  I am trying to schedule this on hourly basis. The schedular calls my batch file correctly but it does not run the other batch files which I am calling internally! Any idea why this is not working?

When I run my batch file manually outside the scheduler... it works! Its only with the scheduler that it cannot run the other batch files.  I have already tried the UCA option.

Answer (score 2):

I just found that there is an option starts with which is optional but you have to put the path till the folder of your bat file in this option to make the bat run properly. Now the bat file works!